# making table row clickable for ajax call in the same time support for right click & open in new window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a page displaying list in the table. I have called a javascript function on each td click using . Now I have to make each row right click-able also & appear "Open in new Window" option like for hyperlinks so that the user can open the details in new page.

Can this be possible, supporting "onclick" & "open in new window" for the same table?

Answer (score 0):

Check this [link](http://elouai.com/javascript/javascript-popup-menu.php) (I searched for you). What it does is applying a function to the `oncontextmenu` event. I'm not sure how that work cross-browser but it should give you a start for what you're trying to do. There's pretty much a lot of those on the web, just search for the right one.

Comment: This is also a good solution, but I want to ask if we can make to appear default browser context menu or not?

Comment: Not that I know of. The context menu of the browser varies on what you're right clicking, ex. for links the "Open Link in a new window" appears but for images a different menu appears. It's something you can't force to display on elements.

Comment: Don't want to change the context menu, simply want to display default browser context menu on td/tr using some kind of anchor tag but also contains onclick code on each td.